# Custom Collector for Neo4j Legacy Index

Tags: neo4j, lucene

I have a Neo4j application that uses the legacy Lucene indexes on certain relationship properties. Whenever I query these I am looking for exact matches, and all of them. While doing some profiling I discovered that the application is spending a highly disproportionate amount of time retrieving these results as it is pulling them in chunks from a prioritized queue. Given that I do not care about the ordering and want all of the results, what can I do to change the underlying behavior?

From my own searching, I came across Lucene's Collector implementations and it seems like a custom one that collects everything and never bothers scoring could be the answer, but I do not know how I can inject one into Neo4j. I am not opposed to using reflection or other means if it is not actually supported by Neo4j.

The application accesses Neo4j via the embedded Java methods.

Answer (score 1):

We're working on some of that as part of our upgrade to Lucene5, there custom collectors for some of these use-case will be implemented. Hopefully we can make something available in the next weeks.

Comment: Did this make it into version 2.3?

Comment: Unfortunately not, you can look at this: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-lucene5-index it will make it into 3.0